# Why isn't the click fireEvent being called?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to called a mock function using the onClick attribute, testing with React Testing Library. Testing is something I'm trying to improve, but from what I understand so far with what I have.

What I'm testing is that a function is called when the button is clicked, I'm rendering the component (styled component) which is being passed the function as a prop.

(The function it self is asynchronous, but because I'm just mocking that a function is being called on the button I'm just using getBy)

Test file

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import QuoteButton from "../Components/QuoteButton";

test("fire event from QuoteButton component", () => {
    const mockCollect = jest.fn();
    render(<QuoteButton onClick={mockCollect}>get a quote</QuoteButton>);
    const buttonElement =  screen.getByRole("button", { name: /get a quote/i });
    fireEvent.click(buttonElement);
    expect(mockCollect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Component

```
import styled from 'styled-components'

const StyledButton = styled.button`
    cursor: pointer;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border-color: #f9a800;

    &:hover {
        background-color: #ff7800;
        color: #fbfbf8
    }
`
const QuoteButton = ({ children, collect }) => {
    return <StyledButton data-testid="quoteButton" onClick={collect}>{children}</StyledButton>
}

export default QuoteButton
```

It is receiving 0 number of calls, is there something else I should be looking for or testing? Any help appreciated. My understand is that because i'm mocking a function with jest.fn() then something must be coming through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a prop called `collect` that's not being passed in your test, instead you're using `onClick`.

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import QuoteButton from "../Components/QuoteButton";

test("fire event from QuoteButton component", () => {
    const mockCollect = jest.fn();
    {/* Wrong: QuoteButton uses 'collect' as a prop */}
    // render(<QuoteButton onClick={mockCollect}>get a quote</QuoteButton>);

    {/* Right: collect will be the prop passed to your internal component's 'onClick' */}
    render(<QuoteButton collect={mockCollect}>get a quote</QuoteButton>); // --> 
    const buttonElement =  screen.getByRole("button", { name: /get a quote/i });
    fireEvent.click(buttonElement);
    expect(mockCollect).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

In the original code you define in your `<QuoteButton>` a `collect` prop and then passes it to your `<button>`'s *onClick*, you're basically saying: onClick -> call collect's reference, please.

Since in your spec you don't send anything to collect to `<QuoteButton>`, it has nothing to call in your spec. Also, since you don't do anything with the received `onClick`, it changes nothing, too.

Comment: I see that now brilliant, thanks a lot for your solution and explanation.